# How to detect padding on an integer and treat it as a string?

Tags: php, sql, string, integer

I have this function to prepare variable to be used in a SQL query:

```
function sqlize($mInput)
{
    if (!isset($mInput))
        $mInput = "null";

    elseif (strtolower($mInput) == "null") { }

    elseif (is_numeric($mInput)) { }

    elseif (is_string($mInput))
    {
        $mInput = trim($mInput);
        $mInput = addslashes($mInput);
        $mInput = '"' . $mInput . '"';
    }
    else
        $mInput = "null";
    return $mInput;
}
```

I have a string "0004", which is going in a "varchar field", is cought by `is_numeric`, and is saved as "4" and not "0004". Is there a way to detect the padding and process it as a string?

Thank you!

***EDIT***

Correct answer based on Cesar and webbiedave tips:

```
    function sqlize($mInput)
    {
        switch(TRUE)
      {
            default: break;
            case (!isset($mInput)): $mInput = "null"; break;
            case (strtolower($mInput) == "null"): break;
            case (is_numeric($mInput)):
                if ((string) intval($mInput) === (string) $mInput)
                    break;
            case (is_string($mInput)):
                    $mInput = trim($mInput);
                    #v2
                    $mInput = $_SESSION['oCore']->oDatabase->sanatize($mInput);
// ADOdb's oDb->qstr();                 
                    # v1
                    #$mInput = addslashes($mInput);
                    #$mInput = '"' . $mInput . '"';
                    break;
        }
        return $mInput;
}
```

Comment: Note: Don't use addslashes to escape data. If you're using mysql_* functions, use mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: adodb's `$db->qstr()` should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `is_numeric()` use `(int)$var == $var` 
I saw a beautiful use of the switch, should be something like this:

```
function sqlize($mInput)
{
    switch(TRUE)
    {
        default:
        case (!isset($mInput)): $mInput = "null"; break;
        case (strtolower($mInput) == "null"): break;
        case (is_numeric($mInput)): break;
        case (is_string($mInput)):
            $mInput = trim($mInput);
            $mInput = addslashes($mInput);
            $mInput = '"' . $mInput . '"';
            break;
    }
    return $mInput;
}
```

Comment: using `elseif ((int)$mInput == $mInput)` triggers on real strings too

Comment: that seems to work:
`case (is_numeric($mInput)): if (intval($mInput) != $mInput) break;`

Comment: great, i saw this use of the switch few days ago here on SO :)

Comment: mmm wouldn't it be `intval($mInput) == $mInput)` ? but it doesn't work as expected that way :S

Comment: 4 == "0004", I must use "==="

Comment: `(string) intval("0004") === "0004"` -> false

Comment: case (is_numeric($mInput) && strlen((int)$mInput) == strlen($mInput)):
try this one